# Roslyn Source Generators Unit Testing error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Console' does not exist in the namespace 'System'

Tags: roslyn, sourcegenerators, csharp-source-generator

I am trying to write a unit test for a simple Roslyn Source Generator based on the [example here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/features/source-generators.cookbook.md#generated-class).

Successfully ran both MsTest as well XUnit Tests as demonstrated in the [Section B of the Unit testing of generators in the cookbook here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/features/source-generators.cookbook.md#unit-testing-of-generators).

My full solution that I ran is [here for you to see](https://github.com/AvtsVivek/RoslynTuts/tree/main/src/Ex30001031).

The problem is as follows. I added a bit more code to the generator. It now looks as below.

```cs
            context.AddSource("MyGeneratedFile.cs", SourceText.From(@"
namespace GeneratedNamespace
{
    public class GeneratedClass
    {
        public static void GeneratedMethod()
        {
            // generated code
            System.Console.WriteLine(""Hello..."");
        }
    }
}", Encoding.UTF8));
        }
```

Note that I [added the following line](https://github.com/AvtsVivek/RoslynTuts/blob/487d4d34741c0cf06996ccb51117ec37e8655265/src/Ex30001031/SimpleCustomGenerator/CustomGenerator.cs#L23)

```
System.Console.WriteLine(""Hello..."");
```

Now when I run the test, the test fails. Looking [into the diagnostic object](https://github.com/AvtsVivek/RoslynTuts/blob/487d4d34741c0cf06996ccb51117ec37e8655265/src/Ex30001031/SimpleCustomGenerator.xUnitTests/CustomGeneratorTests.cs#L45) I see the following error.

> error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Console' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Definitely I am missing something.

New to Roslyn stuff, so how can I make the test pass? How do I add some references to the assembly that holds System namespace?

One way is to simply comment out [the offending line](https://github.com/AvtsVivek/RoslynTuts/blob/487d4d34741c0cf06996ccb51117ec37e8655265/src/Ex30001031/SimpleCustomGenerator.xUnitTests/CustomGeneratorTests.cs#L47), and yes its passing that way. But I am curious. How do I attach the required assembly that it is looking for?

### Update

As @Youssef13 suggested, I added the [MetadataReference for the console type](https://github.com/AvtsVivek/RoslynTuts/blob/f1f0eac633e666894ea4e18b2510a724d5ea00bb/src/Ex30001031/SimpleCustomGenerator.xUnitTests/CustomGeneratorTests.cs#L70)

So that issue is gone, but now the following appears.

> error CS0012: The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

I tried to add [another MetadataReference for System.Object here](https://github.com/AvtsVivek/RoslynTuts/blob/f1f0eac633e666894ea4e18b2510a724d5ea00bb/src/Ex30001031/SimpleCustomGenerator.xUnitTests/CustomGeneratorTests.cs#L71), but this did not resolve it, the above persists.

How do I add a ref to System.Runtime?

### Update 2.

Now I resolved it [by adding the ref](https://github.com/AvtsVivek/RoslynTuts/blob/fe1737671579d7edec7d032b048d2505285746b5/src/Ex30001031/SimpleCustomGenerator.xUnitTests/CustomGeneratorTests.cs#L74) as follows. [Take a look at it here](https://github.com/AvtsVivek/RoslynTuts/blob/fe1737671579d7edec7d032b048d2505285746b5/src/Ex30001031/SimpleCustomGenerator.xUnitTests/CustomGeneratorTests.cs#L74).

```cs
var systemRuntime = Assembly.Load("System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a");
var systemRuntimeRef = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(systemRuntime.Location);
```

Answer (score 1):

I very very recommend the "Solution A" of the unit testing from the document you linked. But for "Solution B", you'll have to provide the assembly containing `Console` class. You can do that using:

```cs
MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(Console).Assembly.Location)
```

There is an `IEnumerable<MetadataReference>` parameter for `CSharpCompilation.Create`.

The testing library, however, does include everything you need for whatever .NET version you want. Which is more flexible.

Comment: Can you take a look at my update, I am now getting error CS0012: The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'